# R removes 00:00:00 from dates just in midnight

Tags: r, datetime

I'm working with R, and I have a code that reads dates from a database. However, I've noticed that when the date is at midnight (e.g., "2024-01-01 00:00:00"), R doesn't store the time component (%H:%M:%S).

I'm currently using version 4.3.2, and I suspect this behavior might be related to the version.

You can reproduce the issue with the following code snippet:

```
datetest <- as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "CET")
print(datetest)  # Output: "2024-01-01 CET"

datetest <- as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 01:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "CET")
print(datetest)  # Output: "2024-01-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

My question is: How can I force R to store the complete date and time value in an object of class POSIXct?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It stores. It's just a matter of output format:

```r
datetest <- as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "CET")

format(datetest, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#> [1] "2024-01-01 00:00:00"

format(datetest, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") |>
  print()
#> [1] "2024-01-01 00:00:00"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-28 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, in that case it works but the problem is that I save in a .csv the dates and the time component "00:00:00" is missing.

Comment: "the problem is that I save in a .csv the dates and the time component "00:00:00" is missing": then please revise your question so it accurately reflects your problem.  Your question, as stated, has been answered, but your comment indicates that it is not your *real* problem.